# 'Can't play this video' using VideoView in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-videoview

I am getting a 'Can't play this video' error while running my app. Looked for some similar questions but the problem didn't solve.

(I am running the app on an actual device. I have set minSdkVersion to 23 and targetSdkVersion to 30.)

Please let me know if i need to attach any other code.

VideosActivity.java :

```
public class VideosActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ActivityVideosBinding binding;
ArrayList<Videos> videos;
VideosAdapter videosAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = ActivityVideosBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    videos = new ArrayList<>();
    videosAdapter = new VideosAdapter(videos);

    Videos videosmodel1 = new Videos("https://www.pexels.com/video/ocean-view-on-the-ship-6815712/", "Love Nature", "Nature is Love");
    videos.add(videosmodel1);

    Videos videosmodel2 = new Videos("https://www.pexels.com/video/aerial-shot-of-a-landscape-8820216/", "Love Nature", "Nature is Love");
    videos.add(videosmodel2);

    Videos videosmodel3 = new Videos("https://www.pexels.com/video/ocean-view-on-the-ship-6815712/", "Love Nature", "Nature is Love");
    videos.add(videosmodel3);

    Videos videosmodel4 = new Videos("https://www.pexels.com/video/ocean-view-on-the-ship-6815712/", "Love Nature", "Nature is Love");
    videos.add(videosmodel4);

    Videos videosmodel5 = new Videos("https://www.pexels.com/video/ocean-view-on-the-ship-6815712/", "Love Nature", "Nature is Love");
    videos.add(videosmodel5);

    binding.viewPagerVideos.setAdapter(videosAdapter);
}
```

Videos Model :

```
public class Videos {

String videoURL, videoTitle, videoDesc;

public Videos(String videoURL, String videoTitle, String videoDesc) {
    this.videoURL = videoURL;
    this.videoTitle = videoTitle;
    this.videoDesc = videoDesc;
}

public Videos() {
}

public String getVideoURL() {
    return videoURL;
}

public void setVideoURL(String videoURL) {
    this.videoURL = videoURL;
}

public String getVideoTitle() {
    return videoTitle;
}

public void setVideoTitle(String videoTitle) {
    this.videoTitle = videoTitle;
}

public String getVideoDesc() {
    return videoDesc;
}

public void setVideoDesc(String videoDesc) {
    this.videoDesc = videoDesc;
}
```

}

Videos Adapter:

```
public class VideosAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VideosAdapter.ViewHolder> {

ArrayList<Videos> videos;

public VideosAdapter(ArrayList<Videos> videos) {
    this.videos = videos;
}

@NonNull
@NotNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_video_screen, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.setVideoData(videos.get(position));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return videos.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    //SingleVideoScreenBinding binding;
    VideoView videoView;
    TextView textVideoTitle, textVideoDesc;
    ProgressBar videoProgressBar;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        //binding = SingleVideoScreenBinding.bind(itemView);
        videoView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        textVideoTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textVideoTitle);
        textVideoDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textVideoDesc);
        videoProgressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoProgressBar);
    }

    void setVideoData(Videos videosmodel){
        videoView.setVideoPath(videosmodel.getVideoURL());
        textVideoTitle.setText(videosmodel.getVideoTitle());
        textVideoDesc.setText(videosmodel.getVideoDesc());

        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                videoProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mp.start();

                /*float videoRatio = mp.getVideoWidth() / (float)mp.getVideoHeight();
                float screenRatio = videoView.getWidth() / (float)videoView.getHeight();
                float scale  = videoRatio / screenRatio;
                if (scale >= 1f){
                    videoView.setScaleX(scale);
                }else {
                    videoView.setScaleY(1f / scale);
                }*/
            }
        });
        videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly use this link because it's not a link to the actual video itself but rather it is just API Request Url which Pexels passes in it's javascript function and then Pexel's servers return the actual link to the video and the player renders the video from that Url. And we can't access this link directly.

Comment: I have tried giving paths of videos downloaded in my system or paths of other random videos but its just not working. @vaibhavgoyal

Comment: Check the code Vaibhav. I have added the Adapter :)